# Remotely accessing mySQL through SSH in Java

Tags: java, mysql, ssh

I'm trying to connect my local Java application to a remote mySQL server. I have shell access to the server and its mySQL, but no root access.

I attempted to implement some code I found online that seems to accomplish this goal. First I SSH into the server, and then I attempt to access the mySQL database. However, I get the following error:

```
Jul 09, 2014 2:20:06 PM [myClassName] connect
SEVERE: null,  message from server: "Host '[remoteHost]' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

I understand that mySQL by default disallows remote client access, but what I don't understand is that in this case it seems to be disallowing itself access to its own mySQL server. (i.e. ["remoteHost"] in the error message is the same host as the one that hosts the mySQL server I'm trying to access.)

The code template I'm using is below. I've left all the fields (user, pass, host, etc.) the same as on the template for the purposes of this question.

Do I need to ask my system administrator to give me special permissions? I have no trouble accessing the mySQL server through terminal. Thanks in advance everyone

Credit to The Kahimyang Project (http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1337/ssh-tunneling-with-java-a-database-connection-example).

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class MysqlManager {

    // Logger
    private final static Logger LOGGER =
            Logger.getLogger(MysqlManager.class.getName());

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MysqlManager mng = new MysqlManager ();
        mng.connect();
    }

    public void connect() {

        // 
        int assigned_port;   
        final int local_port=3309;

        // Remote host and port
        final int remote_port=3306;
        final String remote_host="kahimyang.info";

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch(); 

            // Create SSH session.  Port 22 is your SSH port which
            // is open in your firewall setup.
            Session session = jsch.getSession("user", remote_host, 22);
            session.setPassword("ssh_password");

            // Additional SSH options.  See your ssh_config manual for
            // more options.  Set options according to your requirements.
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            config.put("Compression", "yes");
            config.put("ConnectionAttempts","2");

            session.setConfig(config);

            // Connect
            session.connect();            

            // Create the tunnel through port forwarding.  
            // This is basically instructing jsch session to send 
            // data received from local_port in the local machine to 
            // remote_port of the remote_host
            // assigned_port is the port assigned by jsch for use,
            // it may not always be the same as
            // local_port.

            assigned_port = session.setPortForwardingL(local_port, 
                    remote_host, remote_port);

        } catch (JSchException e) {            
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage()); return;
        }

        if (assigned_port == 0) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Port forwarding failed !"); 
            return;
        }

        // Database access credintials.  Make sure this user has
        // "connect" access to this database;

        // these may be initialized somewhere else in your code.
        final String database_user="user";
        final String database_password="password";
        final String database = "database";

        // Build the  database connection URL.
        StringBuilder url =
                new StringBuilder("jdbc:mysql://localhost:");

        // use assigned_port to establish database connection
        url.append(assigned_port).append ("/").append(database).append ("?user=").
                append(database_user).append ("&password=").
                append (database_password);

        try {
            Class.forName(
                    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            java.sql.Connection connection =
                    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url.toString());

            java.sql.DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();

             // Get all the tables and views
            String[] tableType = {"TABLE", "VIEW"};                       
            java.sql.ResultSet tables = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", tableType);
            String tableName;
            while (tables.next()) {
                tableName = tables.getString(3);

                // Get the columns from this table
                java.sql.ResultSet columns = 
                        metadata.getColumns(null, tableName, null, null);

                String columnName;
                int dataType;
                while (columns.next()) {
                    columnName = columns.getString(4);
                    dataType = columns.getInt(5);

                    // Your actual task;
                }
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException |
                IllegalAccessException |
                InstantiationException |
                java.sql.SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To figure out if your problem is Java-related or not, you could try to `telnet` to the SQL server.

```
$ telnet localhost 3306
```

If you are not allowed to connect, you will receive an error message similar to yours.
To allow access, your system administrator needs to run something like this:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

mysql> use mysql

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

About your concern (SQL server disallowing access from localhost): access should only allowed, if it is really necessary. So if you have only remote SQL clients, there is no need to allow access from the host `localhost`.